# Selenium, python, focus on element

Tags: python, selenium, прокрутка

У меня есть список с разными вкладками, он подгружается постепенно (scroll), я могу найти элемент, который мне нужен, но я не могу кликнуть на него, потому что он недоступен (ошибка element click intercepted). Во время дебага я могу выбрать этот элемент и раскрыть его, тогда в браузере он автоматически появляется (т.е. скролится до нужного элемента). Как это сделать с помощью кода?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в selenium сделать задержку, чтобы подождать, пока отработает весь начальный Javascript на странице:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```